# Python-trouble accessing elements

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm new to Python, so apologies if this question seems a bit basic.

I've a file with the following format-

```
1 1193 5 978300760
1 661 3 978302109....
```

and the idea is to read each line to a list and access the 2nd element in the list.

Now I did the list bit

```
 f.open('c:/filename.dat','r')
 element=f.readline()
```

If I print `element[1]` it shows a blank space and `element[2]` shows 1, so I guess its only taking the 1st digit of the 2nd element and not the number as a whole.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Could you show your code for breaking the line into a list? The results you're getting are also what you'd get if it were just treating the whole line as a string.

Comment: @octern He is. He is only getting the first line and reading it as a string.

Comment: Read the line [ readline( ) ], split it [ split( ) ] and then access the second element [ el[1] ]. Like axblount suggested.

Answer (score 2):

You're reading in the line, but you're not splitting it into columns. Try

```
element = f.readline().split()
```

Now `element[0]` is the first column, `element[1]` is the second, and so on.

Here's the documentation for the `split` function: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split

Answer (score 0):

You are reading firstline only.Try this using `split` method

```
with open('c:/filename.dat') as f:
    for i in f:
        print i.split()[1]

#output
1193
661
```